# What are the plugins or tools to compress static resource files like JS/CSS for Play?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

We want to include this compression process when we are doing the deploy.   On the deploy process,  we have a make-dist to run all the shell script. We were using  mvn -B -q yuicompressor:compress, but when our project migrate to play, Maven is no longer working. Therefore, SBT plugins would be ideal since we do run activator console.

Here are some plugins what I have tried.

- [sbt-yui compressor](https://github.com/indrajitr/sbt-yui-compressor), but it's not working because we are using sbt 0.13 that uses Scala 2.10.3. And this compressor compile by scala 2.9.2
- sbt-closure compressor https://github.com/eltimn/sbt-closure or https://github.com/untyped/sbt-plugins -- this is working, but it is very ugly because it required too many operations while we doing it. For example,  we don't use less but in order to genreate *.min.css, we have to clone css.file with less extention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the plugins listed in the [Build improvements](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23) section - sbt-web? Under [Available Plugins](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web#available-plugins) you can find [sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify) that says:

> An SBT plugin to perform UglifyJs optimization.

that in turn leads to [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) that claims to be *a JavaScript compressor/minifier written in JavaScript.*